# android rounded rectangle drawable question

Tags: android

[image]

I used the source code below to create the above background image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white100" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/gray_BB"

                />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_F4" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/gray_BB"
                />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

There was a problem that the two gray areas of the center view overlap and appear in 2dp.

How can I display only 1dp without overlapping the center view gray?

++

[image]

This is the image I am trying to achieve

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sdghasemi I have posted an image of what I want to achieve.

Comment: So the overlapping would not be an issue only the `1dp` height of the line in the middle is bothering you, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to make the middle line 1dp. @Sdghasemi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the height of the most front drawable as much as it overlays the one underneath and covers its stroke:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        ...
    </item>
    <!-- This item overlays the other -->
    <item
        android:height="41dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        ...
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Note that your view height has to be `80dp` for the drawable to overlap and cover properly.

[image: Final result]

Comment: This answer worked for me. Does this mean that the middle view is invisible because the top view overwrites the bottom view?

Comment: There are actually two drawables with stroke but in order to hide the bottom stroke of first drawable (the one with with gravity `top`) we increase the height of the other drawable (with gravity `bottom`) as much as it hides it and shows 1 stroke in the middle instead of two (which belongs to the bottom drawable). The whole `layer-list` drawable is set on a view with a reasonable height (`80dp`) and the middle line stays `1dp` as we were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It is not implementable with `layer-list`. Also, if you don't want any overlap, and still want 1dp, which color would that line be?

Comment: I want the same gray as the question.

Comment: There are two grays in the question